# Running 3 child processes

Tags: c++, linux

I have three child process and one parent.

I want the program runs in that order [ Child1 then child2 then child3 then parent ].

I have been trying to do with the follwing code but it dose not give me right sequence!

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    pid_t ch11;
    pid_t ch22;
    pid_t ch33;
    int ch1 = fork();
    int ch2 = fork();
    int ch3 = fork();


    if (ch1==0) //child1
    {    cout<<"this is child 1\nGoing from 1 to child 2 ...\n\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    else if ( ch2==0)
    {    waitpid(ch11,0,0);
        cout<<"This is child 2\nGoing from 2 To Child 3 ...\n\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (ch3==0)
    {    waitpid(ch22,0,0);
        cout<<"This is child 3\nFineshed !! going from 3 to parent\n\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {    waitpid(ch33,0,0);
        cout<<"This is parent , waited the whole childes to finish !!\n\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~$ c++ a.cpp -o p1
ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~$ ./p1
This is child 2
Going from 2 To Child 3 ...

this is child 1
Going from 1 to child 2 ...

this is child 1
Going from 1 to child 2 ...

this is child 1
Going from 1 to child 2 ...

This is child 2
Going from 2 To Child 3 ...

This is child 3
Fineshed !! going from 3 to parent

this is child 1
Going from 1 to child 2 ...

This is parent , waited the whole childs to finish.
```

I know that it will be solved by using `waitpid()` function ,  I think im using the `waitpid()` wrong.

Comment: _"... lot  of errors ..."_, isn't very helpful to diagnose your problem. Please elaborate about these errors, [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30154922/edit).

Comment: BTW, after the last `fork()`, you have currently 8 processes, not just 4.

Comment: @Jarod42 ... I'm Sorry i didn't notice this mistake , i have edited the code and compiled it but it still giving me the upove errors + how do i have now 8 processes not just 4 ?

Comment: The second "fork()" is also executed by the first child.The last call is executed by the parent, the first child created by the first "fork()", and the two children created by the second "fork()", so, at the end, you have 8 processes.

Comment: There are still many errors as you have not used the header file for `fork()` which is `#include <unistd.h> I would recommend looking at the [fork man page ](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork). 
Also you should go about it be making a fork inside of a fork, so a fork in the child process that way it will go from having two processes to four processes.

Comment: i had some errors in the code and i edited it , the code is working but it gives me the wrong sequence of executing , i know how to do it in the right way if did it as you side by using a fork inside a fork ,,, but the problem is i have to do each child independently

Comment: You could improve your diagnostics by including the result of `getpid()` in your various printing operations.  This would at least show you how many different processes you have around — 8, as the comments say, not 4 as you seem to think.  If you want child 1 to execute before child 2, then you need to create child 2 after child 1 has completed.  If you kick off the children, they will run free and do as they wish — children aren't easily controlled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a better instrumented version of your code; it includes the PID in the output, and the outputs are one line each.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int ch1 = fork();
    int ch2 = fork();
    int ch3 = fork();

    if (ch1 == 0) // child1
    {
        cout << (int)getpid() << ": This is child 1 - Finished\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (ch2 == 0)
    {
        waitpid(ch1, 0, 0);
        cout << (int)getpid() << ": This is child 2 - Finished\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (ch3 == 0)
    {
        waitpid(ch2, 0, 0);
        cout << (int)getpid() << ": This is child 3 - Finished!\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        waitpid(ch3, 0, 0);
        cout << (int)getpid() << ": This is parent - waited for all children to finish!\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./3kids
40287: This is child 3 - Finished!
40285: This is child 1 - Finished
40286: This is child 2 - Finished
40290: This is child 1 - Finished
40289: This is child 2 - Finished
40288: This is child 1 - Finished
40284: This is parent - waited for all children to finish!
40291: This is child 1 - Finished
$
```

As you can see, there is one process that considers itself to be child 3, two processes that consider themselves to be child 2, and four processes that consider themselves to be child 1 and one that considers itself to be the parent.  This is consistent with the unconstrained forking which creates 8 processes.

To have 3 children only, and to wait for each in turn, you need code more like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

void child(int n)
{
    flush(cout);        // No pending output
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        cerr << (int)getpid() << ": failed to fork\n";
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        cout << (int)getpid() << ": This is child " << n << " - Finished\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        int corpse;
        int status;
        while ((corpse = wait(&status)) != -1)
            cout << (int)getpid() << ": PID " << corpse << " exited with status "
                 << status << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    child(1);
    child(2);
    child(3);
    cout << (int)getpid() << ": This is parent - waited for all children to finish!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./3kids
40336: This is child 1 - Finished
40335: PID 40336 exited with status 0
40337: This is child 2 - Finished
40335: PID 40337 exited with status 0
40338: This is child 3 - Finished
40335: PID 40338 exited with status 0
40335: This is parent - waited for all children to finish!
$
```

Comment: First of all, i didn't have the chance to study about most of what you used in your code, like [ flush(cout) ] , and [ cerr << (int)getpid() << ": failed to fork\n"; ]  but i can understand what did they do ,,, Secondly, i have a question, by the way you have implemented it its absolutely correct, but isn't this making more than one parent ? and question is, where or how did the [ &status ] variable changed ? is this suppose to be the return value from child process ?

Comment: And I'm sorry every one, you all were right , i can now understand why my produced 8 processes not just 4 .

Comment: The `wait()` system call sets `status` to hold the exit status from the child (but here they all return 0 which is really rather boring).  There are plenty of questions that cover the details (a suitable SO search term might be '[c] waitpid').

Answer (score 1):

Despite your comment "the code is working but it gives me the wrong sequence of executing" the whole thing is still completely incorrect and it is obvious you did not understand what other people tried to say, hence I'll make an attempt here.

```
int main()
{
    pid_t ch11;
    pid_t ch22;
    pid_t ch33;
```

What is the purpose of these variables?

```
    int ch1 = fork();
```

Have you read fork manpage? It clearly states when a child process is created it returns 0 in the child and pid in the parent. It can also fail, so you should have checked for that.

With this in mind....

```
    int ch2 = fork();
```

Both the child and the parent **reach this line**. Hence previously created child **forks as well**.

```
    int ch3 = fork();
```

Guess what.

```
    if (ch1==0) //child1
    {    cout<<"this is child 1\nGoing from 1 to child 2 ...\n\n";
```

Except you are not (see below).

```
        exit(0);
```

Should be _Exit.

```
    }
    else if ( ch2==0)
    {    waitpid(ch11,0,0);
```

What? ch11 is not even initialized, so what was this supposed to accomplish?
Do you compile your code with warnings enabled?

In general I don't know if you were trying to make the *children* fork and thus create a chain of for processes with parent<->child relationship or you wanted 3 children of the same parent process. If the latter this is just bad, if the former this is even more wrong since you would not be able to just wait for such a process.

```
[snip the rest]
```

Finally, let's address

> the wrong sequence of executing

What?

There are no guarantees whatsoever as to the order of execution of your processes. In fact any number of them can execute for any amount of time and be scheduled out multiple times before any other number of them even gets a chance to run.

Given what was shown up to this point I'm inclined to guess you either misunderstood your homework assignment or are approaching it quite "unconventionally". Either way, I strongly recommend you state the actual problem which was supposed to be addressed with your code.

Comment: There's no file system checking (`fsck(8)`) going on here.  Please keep things clean and tidy.

Comment: Using `_Exit()` means that standard I/O buffers are not flushed, etc.  Using `exit()` means they are.  In this case, I think `exit()` is considerably better than `_Exit()`.

Comment: He used '\n', so relevant buffers were flushed. If we are talking about a general situation, blindly using exit() is dangerous due to "who knows what" atexit handlers installed.